# When would an Ask Ubuntu account be deleted?

Tags: discussion, ubuntu-community

I know if somebody does something wrong, their account might get deleted but could you please list out the wrong things that we shouldn't do.

Answer (score 6):

The short answer is: Accounts that don't comply with the [terms of service](http://stackexchange.com/legal).

The longer answer is it's completely discretionary. We try our best to engage with users before it comes to deletion. We talk to them and point out the problems and ask them to improve. In repeated instances, we can and do suspend users. It's really only very persistent offenders that warrant deletion.

There are of course exceptions for when we find accounts that are only here to :

- Post junk,
- Harass other people,
- Form part of an automated voting circle (sockpuppets), or
- Circumvent existing suspensions.

I like to think we're pretty decent at doing this safely and if we're unsure, we'll ask Stack Exchange to double-check before anything is done.

Comment: I sent an email to Stack Exchange's email address listed in the Terms of Service for one which I believe to be a definite abuse that should require deletion as well... similar to, but smaller, the automated voting... double (or more) accounts negative voting on good answers... or on any question or answer for that matter.